# Prevent AJAX response from SETTING cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I am trying to PREVENT the response from an AJAX call from setting cookies - which is just the opposite apparently from what most people want, and as a result searching for an answer has been unsuccessful so far.

Typical response headers and body from an AJAX call:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2018 10:14:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=kcmg1k9e; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 2274
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"foo":15,"bar":25}
```

I want to use the JSON but ignore the cookie(s).  How can I do this?  Is there a parameter that can be sent out on the XHR call?